# Xamarin- Copy Data From IntPtr of NSDATA class.Bytes property into uint16 var

Tags: ios, .net, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth

I am creating a blutooth app in Xamarin.ios platform. I am having issues collating data which comes from the peripheral that my app is connected. I have below objective c code but i am having hard time converting it to the C#. As i am not sure how to spilt the array of bytes in c#. Any advice how to correctly receive the data from the device.I thought of using Marshal class but not sure if it does the same thing as it does on iOS operating system level.

this is objective c code which works fine on iOS operating system level

```
   UInt16 cValue;
  [characteristic.value getBytes:&cValue length:2];
```

As you can see it calls getBytes method of NSDATA class From Apple API which does the trick but I could not find something similar in NSDATA class From Xamarin.ios API.

And this is what I think of doing it in C#:

```
byte []destination=new byte[16]();

Marshal.Copy(characteristic.Value.Bytes,destination,2, Not Sure about length);
```

Here's the marshal method that I used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms146631

Last thing,  I am not sure about the byte[16] i just assumed that because Uint16 in objective c  is 8 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: A UInt16 is a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `UInt16` is a 16-bit unsigned integer. `byte[16]` is a 16-byte array of 8-bit unsigned integers.

You will want a `byte[2]` to store the Uint16.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[characteristic.Value.Length];
Marshal.Copy(characteristic.Value.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(characteristic.value.Length));
```

To finally convert to a `ushort` that is the equivalent to an Objective-C `UInt16`, you can use

```
ushort value = (ushort)(bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8))
```

**Update**

For a little-endian `uint` (objc UInt32), the conversion would look like this

```
uint value = bytes[0] | (bytes[1] << 8) | (bytes[2] << 16) | (bytes[3] << 24);
```

Comment: Thanks Etan for sharing. Could explain the last line that you wrote how it takes the value. I mean what << sign means

Comment: a << b means taking the binary representation of _a_, then moving all bits to the left by _b_ bits, then converting back to a number :-)

a << 8 is the same as a * 2^8, or a * 256.

Comment: Hi Etan, I got you what you were explaining about bits and bytes. Another thing that i need to ask is if i have uint32 in objective which is equivalent to uint in c# meaning 32 bit unsigned integers. For this if i have to  create  byteArray i would use byte[] bytes = new byte[4]; which makes perfect sense to me.  But , about the next line how would i convert the value to  uint from byte of 4. In your answer, as i was saying of uint16 you answered that i can use ushort but what would the correspondence for uint.Please apologize me - i am little slow to understand memory structure. Thanks

Comment: Can i use BitConverter class instead of shifting bits ?

Comment: You could but it's discouraged. BitConverter takes endianness from your host. If you process data from the network, you should process it with the endianness of the data as it comes from the network. While BitConverter would work as long as you are only using iPhones, it is not future-proof. Same applies for using things like NSInteger for network structures, as it does not span the same range on 64-bit and 32-bit phones for example. Manual approaches with manual conversions and fixed-size data types are always much safer in such situations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness  <-- wikipedia provides a good overview in how ints are stored in memory.

Comment: You can use Mono.DataConvert, which is a convenient API to do this kind of conversions: http://mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert